# How to scroll to bottom of page, when a new message is sent - Socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I'm attempting to create a chatapp on a webpage. I have a list of messages being sent. Problem is, that the newest messages aren't making the page autoscroll to that message.

I tried:

```
socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
                    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
                    // then you can scroll down once to show the new messages
                    var elem = document.getElementsByName('#messages');
                    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
                });
```

I also tried experienting with the overflow: scroll option No luck there. As well as the position: relative option in the form css (which kinda worked, but unfurtunately the textbox was at the top of the webpage at the start, following the messages downwards - Looks like this:)

The problem I am facing seems to be looking a lot like this stack overflow page

[Scroll HTML page before it 'reaches' the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082870/scroll-html-page-before-it-reaches-the-bottom)

But I did not understand the answer marked as solved

Here is the code I have so far in my html document:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>HF-Chat</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        /* width */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 6px;
        }

        /* Track */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: #2F3136; 
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        /* Handle */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #202225; 
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            font: 13px Roboto;
            color:#DCDDDE;
            background-color: #36393F;
        }

        form {
            background: #36393F;
            padding: 3px;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

            form input {
                background: #484C52; 
                color:#DCDDDE;
                border: 0;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 90%;
                margin-right: .5%;
                margin-left: .2%;
                margin-bottom: .2%;
                border-radius: 5px;
                outline-color: transparent;
            }

            form button {
                width: 9%;
                background: #7289DA;
                border: none;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-bottom: .2%;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

        #messages {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 50px; /*Sets the distance between the textbox and bottom message once enough messages has been sent for the scrollbar to appear */
        }

            #messages li {
                padding: 5px 10px;
                background: #36393F;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #484C52;
            }

                #messages li:nth-child(odd) {
                    background: #36393F;
                }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var socket = io();

                $('form').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading

                    if ($('#m').val().startsWith("/")) {
                        socket.emit('user command', $('#m').val());
                    }
                    else{
                        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                    }
                    $('#m').val('');
                    return false;
                });
                socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
                    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
                    // then you can scroll down once to show the new messages
                    var elem = document.getElementsByName('#messages');
                    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
                });        
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button><font color="#DCDDDE">Send</font></button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to scroll using `.animate`

```
const $li = $('<li>').text(msg);
$('#messages').append($li);

$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $li.offset().top
}, 2000); // change the animation delay to whatever you like
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so so much :D

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past 3 days now haha

Only thing to keep in mind, to whoever might be watching as well looking for a solution. You might wanna set the animation delay to 0 instead of 2000, as the animation will make it look like the messages change places when you scroll up!

Much appreciated and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Get the top offset of the element

```
var offset = $('.element').offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I like event listeners:

```js
document.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function(event) {
        event.composedPath().forEach(function(dom) {
            if (dom.classList && dom.classList.value === "classOfLoadedContent") {
                $(".div-to-be-scrolled").scrollTop($(".content").innerHeight());
            }
        });
    },
    true
);
```